# SSL stripping - initiate HTTPS or HTTP first?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, tls-intercept, sslstrip

I am quite confused. I have been reading about SSL stripping and what I have found is that

1. The client (victim) **has** to initiate the first connection via HTTP
2. The server will redirect to HTTPS  - here is were interception and stripping occurs.

But I have also read articles where the first connection is an HTTPS connection.

I am slightly confused about this. In order for SSL stripping to work (forgetting about the HSTS for now), do we need a client initiating the first connection via HTTP or HTTPS?

[image: Uses HTTPS]
[image: Uses HTTP]

Comment: The answers in the duplicate question also talk about the differences between how the victim initiates the connection. In short, both are possible.

Comment: You are right, sorry @schroeder

Comment: but from what I see, if the client initiates HTTPS connection, the only attack is an SSL MITM attack, which then "defeats the purpose of this attack". @schroeder

Comment: It requires being in the middle anyway, yes. But if you can downgrade the connection to HTTP, you can carry out the SSLstrip style of attack. You could, of course, do other things, but that requires a bad cert that will trow warnings.

Comment: So, original intent of the attack was to keep the HTTP connection HTTP and not "upgrading". But it is possible to downgrade, too, although it might not always make sense. Your question is about what *must* happen. the answer is that there are options.